# How to show profile editing features only to account's owner in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-registration

I'm building a website using Django 1.8.4 and I use django-registration-redux to handle users login and logout.

When all users are logged out, I manually enter a user's profile page, which contains users info and link to edit the profile:

```
url(r'^users/(?P<slug>\w+)/$', UserProfileDetailView.as_view(), name="profile")
```

problem is, when I visit a user's page (i.e. /users/james/) it recognizes me as user "james" logged in (`is_authenticated`) , and show logout and edit profile button, but it shouldn't! it should only show public info. (when I click edit button, it asks me for login credits, so that part works fine)

How can I avoid this situation (showing edit profile, logout, etc. from either random logged in or anonymous users) and only show them to logged in owners of account?

viws.py

```
class UserProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    model       = get_user_model()
    slug_field  = "username"
    template_name = "user_detail.html"

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        user    = super(UserProfileDetailView, self).get_object(queryset)
        UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return user
```

user_detail.html

```
<h2>{{ object.username }}'s Profile</h2>
{% if object.userprofile.bio %}
<div>
<b>Bio:</b>
{{ object.userprofile.bio }}
</div>
{% endif %}

{% if object.username == user.username and user.is_authenticated %}
    <p><a href='{% url "edit_profile" %}'>Edit My Profile</a></p>
{% endif %}

#footer
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a> |
    <a href="{% url 'profile' slug=user.username %}"><b>{{ user.username }}</b></a> 
  {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">Register</a> |
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a> 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What are the values of object.username and user.username?

Comment: I want to check if the user visiting the page is the same user is authenticated. I'm not sure if it's correct at all, and actually here's my problem.

Comment: I want to do the opposite, when i do {{user.userprofile.bio}} only show me the info in the template if i am log in when it should be showing it for alll public, weird, do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "user" variable in your template's context is being overwritten by the current record being viewed.

Try changing

```
{% if object.username == user.username and user.is_authenticated %}
```

to

```
{% if object == request.user and request.user.is_authenticated %}
```